# MySQL: adding previous and current as a default value for a field 'academic-year'

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

So I have a trigger that shows the current year but I want to have a result that will show previous and current year for an academic year.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_year
BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.academic_year = YEAR(NOW());
```

This is what I've tried but it wouldn't really work

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_year
BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.academic_year = YEAR(NOW())-1"-"YEAR(NOW());
```

I want to have an academic year that will show "2018-2019". Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What data type is academic_year and how long?

Comment: that was the problem all along. I set it to INT instead of VARCHAR. Thanks sir @P.Salmon!

Comment: Triggers don't "show" anything.  They tend to modify data.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your concatenation of the years. You need to use the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)-function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_year
BEFORE INSERT ON years
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.academic_year = CONCAT(YEAR(NOW())-1, "-", YEAR(NOW()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the information on concat. Wasn't really aware of that. But output is still "2018" with the query you made. Not "2018-2019". Somehow it only reads the first part